# How Can I add an angular event to a button defined in a Kendo Grid column template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to create a template for a column in my kendo grid. The template includes buttons and I'd like to bind an event to these buttons. The problem I am having is that the template cant reference the scope in controller (at least i think this is the problem).

I have tried using grid.appScope as suggested in this post: [AngularJS : How to access scope from ui-grid cell template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28127207/angularjs-how-to-access-scope-from-ui-grid-cell-template). When I tried this, I get a JS error when I click the button that says grid is not defined. I'm not sure how to define grid within the template - I tried using JQuery within the template but that didnt seem to work.

I also tried external-scopes but I believe this has been depricated for grid.appScope:
[external-scopes no longer works in ui-grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29508506/external-scopes-no-longer-works-in-ui-grid/29513838)

```
    <div id="myGrid" class="overflow-hidden" kendo-grid="myGrid" k-options="myGridOptions"></div>
```

```
$scope.onRadioChange = function (id) { console.log("Here: " + id};


$scope.myGridOptions= {
        dataSource: myDataSource,
        columns: [
            { field: "buttonfield", template: "<label class=\"btn btn-primary\"> <input type=\"radio\" name=\"options-#:id#\" id=\"myButton\" autocomplete=\"off\" checked ng-click=\"onRadioChange(#:id#)\"> Click me</label>"
        ],
        height: 500,
        resizable: false,
        editable: false,
        selectable: "row",
        batch: false,
        sortable: true,
        scrollable: true
    }
```

The above example results in no errors or feed back. Clicking the button does not log to console and the $scope.onRadioChange function is not being called.

How can I call a function defined in my scope from a kendo template? Is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried the method described in [this Telerik knowledge base article](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/grid-angular-click-handler-for-command)?

Comment: That is different from what I am trying to do. That documentation describes how to add a custom event to a command button. I am trying to add an event to a button that is in a template.